# Why logo image is showing in circle?[noob]

Tags: html, css

I am beginner to Front end technology. I AM not sure which part of my code making my logo image showing in circle. Kindly point me what css property making it occuring so. I am new to css and coudnt figure out which property is responsible for this. I have already tested with align items and padding values but nothing is working to change the image oval shape. I want my image to be in square shape or in another shape. If anyone have any idea please point in direction of how you guys resolve this kind of solution.

**HTML file:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <nav class="nav" id="nav-menu">
      <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="header_close"> </ion-icon>
      
      <ul class="nav_list">
        <li class="nav_item"><a href=""class="nav_link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href=""class="nav_link">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href=""class="nav_link">Training</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href=""class="nav_link">Train with us</a></li>
        <li class="nav_item"><a href=""class="nav_link">Contact Us</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="header_toggle"></ion-icon>
  </header>


<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS file:**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,500;1,700&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #222831;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo{
    display: flexbox;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo img{
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.header_logo{
    color: #eeee;
    
}
.nav_list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav_item {
    margin: 0 8px;
}

.nav_link {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #eeee;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of;

```
border-radius: 100%;
```

When you make the border-radius 100% thinner, it turns into a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-radius: 100%;` from your CSS.

```css
.logo img{
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo img{
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You have a problem with this set of code - the border-radius part. In the future, if you'd like to see which class/line causes the error, you can inspect the element and under styles you'll get all the classes that are attached to the element itself. In your browser, you can check/uncheck classes and see which one does the problem.